# How to get the last inserted id in Magento customer address model

Tags: magento

I am saving the customer address in the `customer_address_entity` table. Everything is ok but I  want to get the last generated `entity_id`. Can somebody help me?

I have the following code;

```
        $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

         $customAddress->setData($_custom_address)
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('0')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

         try {
           $customAddress->save();
         } catch (Exception $ex) {
              Mage::log("\n Address save Error:: \n" . $ex->getMessage(), null, $this->log_entry_file);
       }
```

Answer (score 15):

1 - when using a model, this returns the recently added/saved item id by $model object

```
    $model->getId()
```

2 - But when using a custom query , then use following to get last inserted id

```
$connection    = Mage::getSingleton(’core/resource’)->getConnection(’core_write’);
$sql         = "INSERT INTO <table> SET field1 = ?, field2 = ?, ...";
$connection->query($sql, array($field1_value, $field2_value, ...));
$lastInsertId = $connection->lastInsertId();
echo $lastInsertId;
```

3 - From a specific table, get the last inserted id by defining your own function

```
   function getLastInsertId($tableName, $primaryKey)
   {
    //SELECT MAX(id) FROM table
    $db = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $result = $db->raw_fetchRow("SELECT MAX(`{$primaryKey}`) as LastID FROM `{$tableName}`");
    return $result['LastID'];
   }
```

Answer (score 11):

To get the id after saving use `getId()`

```
...
try {
       $customAddress->save();
       echo $customAddress->getId(); 
 }
....
```

Answer (score 5):

```
If you use magento save method than try this to get the last inssert id.

$order->save();
Afetr save method use getId method to get the last insert id in magento 
echo $order->getId(); 


//For custom connection use 
$db_write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ";
$db_write ->query($sqlQuery);
echo $lastInsertId  = $db_write ->fetchOne('SELECT last_insert_id()'); 
                              OR

echo $db_write ->lastInsertId(); // you may also try this.

For more Info
```

[Click Here](http://magentoo.blogspot.com/2014/01/get-last-insert-id-in-magento.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to resolve your query:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname('John')
            ->setLastname('Doe')
            ->setEmail('jd1@ex.com')
            ->setPassword('somepassword');


            $address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
            $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
            ->setMiddleName($customer->getMiddlename())
            ->setLastname($customer->getLastname())
            ->setCountryId('HR')
            ->setPostcode('31000')
            ->setCity('Osijek')
            ->setTelephone('0038511223344')
            ->setFax('0038511223355')
            ->setCompany('Inchoo')
            ->setStreet('Kersov')
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        try{
            $address->save();
            $lastId = $address->getId(); // Last id
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a magento method for that:

```
$table = $model->getResource()->getMainTable();

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection();
$id = $connection->lastInsertId($tableName);
```

Comment: How can we get it in m2?

Comment:  Only doing M1 :-) But feel free to open another question!

Answer (score 0):

```
$freeevent = Mage::getModel('freeevent/freeevent');
$freeevent->setData('firstname', $firstname);
$freeevent->setData('lastname', $lastname);
$freeevent->save();
$getLastId = $freeevent->getId();
```

use this code to get the last inserted id in magento .